# Using multithreading get response from different urls

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading, servlets

I am making an ajax call to a Java servlet which gets response from different urls and manipulate the data before sending back. Now as there are many urls, to speed up the process rather than sequential processing I have used CountDownLatch and made a class for each url response(which I will use for multithreading). I am not able to understand how to send data back from each response class to the main servlet so that I can manipulate and send back the data to ajax call.

Here's the doget() of my servlet which is called through ajax call.

```
private static CountDownLatch _latch;
private static int N = 2;
_latch = new CountDownLatch(N);
try {
new Thread(new FirstUrl(_latch)).start();
new Thread(new SecondUrl(_latch)).start();
_latch.await();
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here are the url response classes.

```
 public class SecondUrl implements Runnable {

private CountDownLatch _latch = null;
public SecondUrl(CountDownLatch _latch) {
    this._latch = _latch;
}


public void run() {
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri = new URI("http://url1.com");
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(uri.toURL().openStream());
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
        _latch.countDown();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }    
 }
```

Similarly, there is another class with a different url. How to send the JSONObject result back to servlet, so that I can manipulate it.

I am new to multithreading so I might be wrong about any approach. Feel free to point out. Thanks.

Comment: Personally I would use ajax promises and wait for them all to complete,

Comment: If you had methods on the SecondUrl that returned the result, and you created a concrete instance of SecondUrl then you could call this method after await has finished

Comment: @ScaryWombat  I will try through ajax too, thanks for that. For calling through functions should I define a default constructor? Because the constructor of FirstUrl takes latch as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the Callable instead of Runnable. Look at [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface.

Comment: Yeah Futures - that's the story

Answer (score 0):

One (of the many) way (to pass result back from your threads) is to pass to your threads a reference to a ArrayBlockingQueue that is initialized in your main thread. The result can be added to the queue. In the main thread, you can either process as the data becomes available or process at the end (after you finish you _latch.await()).

Answer (score 0):

try using a synchronized method to 'join' result in each individual thread, Using Runnable is fine.

And you don't need a second class for SecondUrl. you can use a single class and you can pass the url as a parameter to the class.